# How to redirect a specific page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've looked all over for the htaccess code to redirect a single page and haven't had any luck with many solutions.

Basically I need to redirect this:

```
/example/my-stuff/
```

to:

```
/example/home/
```

but I don't want any other pages except for /my-stuff/ to be redirected. Eg. these pages should not be redirected and kept the same.

```
/example/my-stuff/a-page
/example/my-stuff/anything
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, you can add either this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/my-stuff/$ /example/home/
```

Or you can use mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/my-stuff/$ /example/home/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Neither of them worked properly though, I need to make sure only /my-stuff/ is redirected, not /my-stuff/subfolder/ or anything like that.

Comment: @huzibizi  was missing a `$` at the end of the redirect match, it should only redirect `/example/my-stuff/`. the `$` indicates an end of the match, so it won't match against anything more.