# Use .htaccess to remove directory folder from WordPress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to remove a folder from my WordPress URL in a particular case:

From:

```
http://capitulardesign.com.br/blog/portfolio/70-anos-sinduscon/
```

To:

```
http://capitulardesign.com.br/portfolio/70-anos-sinduscon/
```

But the rule must work only on `/blog/portfolio/` cases. The WordPress is installed on `/blog/` folder and the normal website (custom PHP pages mixed with WordPress Codex codes) is in the root folder.

Plus: The `/portfolio/` is a Custom Post Type taxonomy.

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045205/how-to-redirect-a-specific-page-using-htaccess

Comment: Did not work, not even redirected the match.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/portfolio/$ /portfolio/ [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

That would be a really, hmmm... ineffective solution.

1. Have you considered to alter the `rewrite_rules` and change portfolio "term" link with `term_link`?

   Check out what current rules of the `portfolio` using `portfolio_rewrite_rules` filter and change links to them using [`term_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/term_link) filter.
2. Another way to solve this will be to change `with_front` (to `false`) of your `rewrite` element of arguments array for taxonomy portfolio (while [`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)).

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in main root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+portfolio/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/portfolio/(.*)$ portfolio/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ blog/portfolio/$1 [L]
```

The scenario is to redirect any request for `/blog/portfolio/` to `/portfolio/` then internally redirect any  `/portfolio/` to `/blog/portfolio/` .

**Note:** clear your browser cache and test it , if Ok , change `302` to `301` to be permanent redirection

Comment: Yes! It works, now I just need to adjust the URL in the PHP loop to remove the /blog/ from the URL. But, for some reason I'm free to access from both URLs.

Comment: could you able to access blog/portfolio from browser without redirecting to portfolio?

Comment: Yes, I'm not being redirected automatically. I need to change manually the URL in the browser.

Comment: did you put it in root ,htaccess file or other directory ?

Comment: Yes, in the root. Also `/public_html` my WordPress are in `/public_html/blog`

Answer (score -1):

use better search replace plugin to replace your url.
old url

```
http://capitulardesign.com.br/blog/portfolio/
```

New url

```
http://capitulardesign.com.br/portfolio/
```

No need of htaccess

Comment: Don't work for me, because I'm not moving the entire site from /blog/ to /, I want to change only on this particular case of URL as /blog/portfolio/

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^capitulardesign.com.br
RewriteRule ^blog/portfolio/(.*)$ portfolio/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^capitulardesign.com.br
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/portfolio/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please explain how your solution fixes the problem.