# My htaccess passthrough rule redirects to the url instead

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm trying to passthrough (not redirect!) an empty old page to its new location using an htaccess RewriteRule.

I essentially want the user to browse to `mysite.com/page-old` and to see that url in their browser but be delivered the content from `mysite.com/page-new`.  The user should not be aware that the location changed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-old/?$ /page-new [PT]
```

The actual result is that they are *redirected* to page-new instead.

I found the below on apache.org which seems to validate my code some, but this is giving me a 404 error.

> Description:
> Assume we have recently renamed the page foo.html to bar.html and now want to provide the old URL for backward compatibility. However, we want that users of the old URL even not recognize that the pages was renamed - that is, we don't want the address to change in their browser
> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html

```
RewriteRule "^/foo\.html$" "/bar.html" [PT]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045205/how-to-redirect-a-specific-page-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^example/my-stuff/$ /example/home/ [L,R=301]
```

check this answer as well

[How to redirect a specific page using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045205/how-to-redirect-a-specific-page-using-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  The sample code you provided as well as the other answer are different from my problem set.  They both work for me as a redirection, but my challenge is trying to enable a "passthrough" rule that <em>hides</em> the new site location...

My issue right now is that my passthrough rule and your redirect one are behaving the same...